# Creating a deliverable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello im a student taking a Computational Techniques Course, and learning Matlab. 
Ive been asked to generate a plot with the following conditions:

x range of the data -2pi to pi

Data spacing should be 0.1 apart

Data points should be marked with blue circles

Label the x-axis'independent variable' and the y-axis'dependent variable'

Give the plot a title

I've completed these things, but am unsure how to . . . gather everything together that I need. Im assuming that a deliverable is a single file or bit of code the professor can load into his Matlab and run to see if it produces the required results. Is there a command that completes this?

Here is the code/workspace that I have so far

Workspace

```
x = -2*pi:0.1:pi
y = cos(x)
plot (x,y,'bo'}
```

Script

```
function createfigure(X1, Y1)

figure1 = figure;

axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1);
box(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');

plot(x,y,'Marker','o','LineStyle','none','Color',[0 0 1]);

xlabel({'Independent Variables'});

ylabel({'Dependent Variables'});

title({'f(x) = cos(x)'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `function`, a simple script will do. I haven't looked into your code, I'm assuming it does what you want it to do.

General rule of thumb:

If you have several scripts, try having one `main`-script that should be executed first. Include comments in the start of the function / script saying what the function does etc. You should make it *very easy* for your professor to check what you have done. Don't let her guess how to execute your script, or have her do a long list of stuff. Anything that one might need to write in the command line can instead be written in a script and execute by a single click.

If you have several scripts, zip them and send it. Again, make sure it's easy to understand what function the professor should execute (if not all). I would suggest having one script she can call without any input, and let that script do everything (i.e. call other functions). Unzip it and test it before sending it! You should be able to run it all without altering anything, and with a clean work space.

```
%% Save as createfigure.m
% I'm assuming the below code is correct.

x = -2*pi:0.1:pi
y = cos(x)
plot (x,y,'bo')

figure1 = figure;

axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1);
box(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');

plot(x,y,'Marker','o','LineStyle','none','Color',[0 0 1]);

xlabel({'Independent Variables'});

ylabel({'Dependent Variables'});

title({'f(x) = cos(x)'});
title({'f(x) = cos(x)'});
```

Comment: In adddition to @RobertPs answer, you can publish your code as html from withim Matlab which gives you a nice documentation. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html